# Using a comparison test to see if a series converges or diverges

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

The series is a sum of $(n^2+1)/(n^3+2)$ to infinity from $n=1$. From previous questions I have seen that you should try to alter the sum to one that is commonly known so a comparison can be made. I have compared it to a series that is always bigger: $(n^2+1)/(n^3) = (1/n) + (1/n^3)$. 
I know and already have the proof that $1/n$ diverges to infinity and $1/n^3 $ converges to a limit, although I am unsure how to use this to show whether or not the two combined diverges or converges. Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1):

$$\forall n\geqslant2,\qquad\frac{n^2+1}{n^3+2}\geqslant\frac1n$$